# Let x_0 = 0 and let x_1, x_2, ..., x_10 follow the rule |x_i - x_{i-1}| = 1 for 1 <= i <= 10. If x_10 = 4, how many possible sequences are there?

Tags: python, math, probability, series

At each node, we must go up or down 1. A couple of possible sequences would be

0,1,2,3,2,3,2,3,2,3,4 or 0,-1,-2,1,2,3,4,5,4,3,4

I saw this question on QuantGuide

I have come across this problem and I do not know how to tackle it. My thoughts at this point are that at each node you have two possible choice, go up 1 or go down 1. If there was no final constraint, the answer would simply be 2^10, but the final constraint x_10 = 4 is throwing me off. I found the solution by brute force in Python by finding the percentage of unconstrained sequences that terminated at 4 however I feel like there must be a neater solution.

The solution to the question is 120 possible sequences is this helps.

Comment: Post your current approach so that answers can be targeted to show how it can be improved.

Comment: I think you can rephrase this question to the number of grid walks from the corner of a grid of size 10 - x_10 by x_10. Imagine a graph plotting the data, and turning it 45 degrees, and looking at the possible grid that forms when forming solutions.

Comment: Permutation with repetition: for the 0->4 case you have 7 ups and 3 downs, 10!/(7!*3!)=120.

Comment: For tackling it with code, you can probably brute-force it with a twist: when you get too far from the target, and the remaining k steps in the given try simply can't get you back, you can give up that try early (instead of checking 2^k times, that yes, the result is something else than 4).

Comment: your question is incomplete. we don't know what nodes is talking about and what the numbers 0,1,2,3,2,3,2,3,2,3,4 represent. In addition, you haven't posted any code, so your question is off-topic

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki I think the title is clear on the problem statement and provides enough information to see where the sequence comes from.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Crude implementation of the comment

> For tackling it with code, you can probably brute-force it with a twist: when you get too far from the target, and the remaining k steps in the given try simply can't get you back, you can give up that try early (instead of checking 2^k times, that yes, the result is something else than 4).

```
start=0
stop=4
size=11 # includes the starting element
results=0

def check(candidate):
  global stop,results
  if len(candidate) == size:  # just safety, the two "if"-s could be an "and"
    if candidate[-1] == stop: # found a solution, happy
      print(candidate)
      results+=1
    return
  if abs(candidate[-1] - stop) > size - len(candidate): # the "shortcut"
    return
  check(candidate + [candidate[-1] + 1])
  check(candidate + [candidate[-1] - 1])

check([start])
print(results)
```

It produces `120` as a result (also prints the actual sequences).

And of course the maths part also suggests that, repeated from comment:

> Permutation with repetition: for the 0->4 case you have 7 ups and 3 downs, 10!/(7!*3!)=120.